# String functions on Tinkerpop Query Language

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Looking in the [Tinkerpop doc](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/reference/#a-note-on-predicates), I could find a list of String functions:

```
TextP.startingWith(string) - Does the incoming String start with the provided String?

TextP.endingWith(string) - Does the incoming String end with the provided String? 

TextP.containing(string) - Does the incoming String contain the provided String?

TextP.notStartingWith(string) - Does the incoming String not start with the provided String?

TextP.notEndingWith(string) - Does the incoming String not end with the provided String?

TextP.notContaining(string) - Does the incoming String not contain the provided String?
```

But, I could not find a way to use them. I also try looking the Javadoc about the TextP in http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/TextP.html, but also could not find any good information over there.

Query filters like this bellow are working fine:

```js
g.V().has( label, within( 'cake', 'coffee' ) ).limit(3)
```

Some examples of queries that I have tested and did not worked:

```js
g.V().label().startingWith('c')
g.V().label().fold().startingWith('c')
g.V().label().fold().has(__.startingWith('c'))
g.V().has(label, startingWith('c'))
g.V().has(label, TextP.startingWith('c'))
g.V().has(label.startingWith('c'))
```

Comment: In case it helps I did a writeup of the Text Predicates here. http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#textpredicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextP` is meant to work like any other `Predicate` and some of the usage you listed is correct:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has(label, startingWith("p")).label()
==>person
==>person
==>person
==>person
gremlin> g.V().has('name', endingWith("o")).values('name')
==>marko
```

As a side note I'm a bit surprised to see no examples in the documentation - I intend to get some added.

Comment: I try to test this command on the https://github.com/bricaud/gremlin-server-3.2.5-REST and it did not work. ```[WARN] HttpGremlinEndpointHandler - Invalid request - responding with 500 Internal Server Error and No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.endingWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [vertex]```

Comment: Also, it does not work with AWS Neptune. What probably is one more limitation in the Amazon implementation.

Comment: `TextP` was added to TinkerPop 3.4.x so I think you could expect it not to work on gremlin-server-3.2.5-REST which is based on TinkerPop 3.2.x. `TextP` should work on Neptune - see examples here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-neptune-now-supports-tinkerpop-3-4-features/

Comment: Looks like it is an AWS issue. These queries does not work on my current Neptune cluster using the offical gremlin client ```g.V().has(label,startingWith('o')).limit(3)```, ```g.V().has(label,TextP.startingWith('o')).limit(3)``` while this works ```g.V().has(label,within('o')).limit(3)```. I am going to open a ticket with them about this.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the current limitations of the Gremlin on AWS Neptune the best way to do it that I could find was:

```js
g.V().has(label, between("c","cz"))
```

This also works for any particular prefix:

```js
g.V().has(label, between("foo","fooz"))
```

Comment: What version of the Neptune engine are you running? I was able to successfully run queries such as these:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel(startingWith('airpo')).count()
==>3497
gremlin> g.V().has(label, startingWith('airpo')).count()
==>3497
```
Also what Gremlin Client version are you using? @ThiagoMata

Comment: A very old one. That is probably the reason.